# Interactive charts in Google Colaboratory using R language

Tags: r, charts, google-colaboratory, visualization, interactive

I'm learning R and colab and what I'm trying is making an interactive chart in colab with R kernel. It seems impossible without a sort of configuring the environment. Not sure if it is possible anyway. My code below:

```
data %>%
  group_by(A1) %>%
    summarise(rec_count = n()) %>%
      hchart("pie", hcaes(x = A1, y = rec_count))
```

I don't consider any alternatives, I just interested in this way. So, my question is: how can I get it to work?